# Remove all links in post content

Tags: posts

How I can remove all internal or external links on my posts at once? just remove link and leave anchor text.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the database but you can do it easily with `the_content` filter, just add the code below to your current (child) theme `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'misha_remove_all_a' );
function misha_remove_all_a( $content ){

    return preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#is', '\1', $content);

}
```

Comment: Obligatory Comment: avoid manipulating HTML with regexps. That one will break on `<a title="and>">`. Just because you wouldn't doesn't mean others won't write wonky stuff in their documents.

Comment: Agreed. I also trying to avoid such stuff, but sometimes you may need fast and easy solution.

Comment: Totally, I'm guilty of that as well. But you have to try to warn those that haven't yet stepped onto this dangerous path ;)

Comment: I with an option here to add likes to comments :)

Comment: thanks, but will not remove it from db, this is just a temporary solution.

Comment: How much posts do you have? Maybe I will help you with another script

Answer (score 0):

Target your links with some CSS. In default twentyseventeen theme it's

```
.entry-content a {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('the_content', 'removelink_content',1);

function removelink_content($content = '')
{
    preg_match_all("#<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a>#i",$content, $matches);
    $num = count($matches[0]);for($i = 0;$i < $num;$i++){
        $content = str_replace($matches[0][$i] , $matches[2][$i] , $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```